# module 'plotly.graph_objs' has no attribute 'Choroplethmapbox'

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to runt his code from plotly website https://plot.ly/python/mapbox-county-choropleth/ 
and it throws this error, which I don't seem to get around with. I have looked into github pages, but only unsuccessfully.

````
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
with urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/geojson-counties-fips.json') as response:
    counties = json.load(response)

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/fips-unemp-16.csv",
                   dtype={"fips": str})

from plotly import graph_objs as go
#import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(go.Choroplethmapbox(geojson=counties, locations=df.fips, z=df.unemp,
                                    colorscale="Viridis", zmin=0, zmax=12,
                                    marker_opacity=0.5, marker_line_width=0))
fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="carto-positron",
                  mapbox_zoom=3, mapbox_center = {"lat": 37.0902, "lon": -95.7129})
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()```
````

Answer (score 1):

This was added in the most recent version of Plotly, which is 4.1.0, so you'll need to upgrade.